# Convert a 1D array of strings into a 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets

I am a bit of a novice here, so I will just jump right into the example of the issue I am having:

I want to convert this: "`cat@dog%arm@hand%tree@apple...`"

into this:

```
cat | dog
arm | hand
tree| apple
..etc
```

As in, 2 columns in the spreadsheet, or a 2D array. Isolating the strings using has not been difficult, it is the array manipulation that is stumping me.

Here is one attempt: `

```
function key_abb(input) {
  if(input.map) { 
    return input.map(key_abb);
  }else {
    var temp = input.toString();
    temp = temp.replace("abbreviated-name=", "");
    temp = temp.replace("name=", "");
    return temp;
  }
}`
```

*input* being an input range that is formatted like this:

```
|abbreviated-name="cat"  name="dog"  |
|abbreviated-name="arm"  name="hand" |...
```

Unfortunately this is still just returning the two strings within the same column, so the only thing that was accomplished was that the extra text was removed, I am not sure how to create the output array that I would like. Thank you!

Comment: You will find value in the [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.

Comment: Hi marty, I have also been trying that, but I am still stuck with a similar problem: How do I get the 1D array sorted into a 2D output array?

Also, how do I do 'code' in the comments?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```js
var str = 'cat@dog%arm@hand%tree@apple';
var data = str.split('%');

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i] = data[i].split('@');
}
    
console.log(data);
```

Results in:

```
[
    ["cat", "dog"],
    ["arm", "hand"],
    ["tree", "apple"]
]
```

Comment: Wow that totally worked, I really just have a difficult time grasping arrays and manipulating them. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var str = 'cat@dog%arm@hand%tree@apple';
var data = str.split('%').map(function(item) {
  return item.split('@');
});
    
console.log(data);
```